# Empty object after function is complete

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile, cordova

After my click function is complete i need to reset all the data within the function. For some reason when the user hits the button again all of the previous information in the contacts object is still there. This is a phonegap application. Thanks

```
$('#updateBtn').click(function() {
            var theContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName" : masterName});
            theContact.id = document.getElementById("txtID").value;  // Update contact by ID
            theContact.name = document.getElementById("txtFirst").value;
            theContact.note = document.getElementById("txtAlias").value;
            alert(masterID); //always returns each contact entry instead of the current object
            theContact.save();




            clearText();

        });
```

Comment: The variable is local, so it's clearly replaced on each execution of the event handlers callback function. Are you perhaps having issues with `navigator.contacts.displayName` not being removed ?

Comment: that could be the issue, but i am editing the contacts by their id and the second time through the old id is still there as well

Comment: if i alert the masterID the second time it will alert each contact i've selected up to that point